# Advantage of using OCSP stapling compared to frequently renewed TLS certificates without OCSP

Tags: tls, ocsp

What's the advantage of using OCSP stapling with some OCSP response validity period compared to a TLS certificate with the same short validity period which would have to be renewed at the same interval as the (stapled) OCSP response would ?

In both cases, the CA must create one signature per validity period and if the CA is informed of a security breach by the TLS certificate's owner, the CA must stop to do so.
In both cases it depends on this validity period how quick clients are informed of an invalid certificate, whether it may be revoked or expired.

So it seems to me both variants are equally secure and put a comparable burden to the CA, but using OCSP seems more complicated for no advantage. Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In both cases, the CA must create one signature per validity period ...

There can be different certificates used for issuing the certificate and for signing the OCSP response. Since the latter can not issue new certificates the impact of a compromise of this OCSP signer certificate is much lower compared to the CA certificate.

This way a well protected CA certificate can be used to issue new certificates less often and accept the usability issues coming with the better protection, like requiring some human interaction before a new certificate gets issued. At the same time the key for the OCSP signer certificate needs less protection and thus can be used for automatic issuing OCSP responses in short intervals.